# Naruto Uzumaki Chronicles 2 .RAW Files [PS2]

Tags: binary-analysis, decompress

I'm have been trying to mod these game for years, but I still stuck with the raw files from RACJIN games, [same case as Fullmetal Alchemist & Bleach]. The files appear to be compressed, and a signature scan using `binwalk` does not return any results. Here is the entropy scan of one of the files:

[image: example entropy scan]

Moreover, a hex dump of the first few bytes in the file do not reveal any obvious header structure:

```
$ hexdump -C -n 256 000001a6_5835296_6.raw 
00000000  00 05 00 ff cd 14 20 58  80 03 02 04 04 b8 20 20  |...... X......  |
00000010  00 90 c0 99 02 18 20 10  a0 00 84 01 13 00 76 0a  |...... .......v.|
00000020  70 c0 40 80 01 20 a0 3e  08 10 08 e2 a7 00 07 10  |p.@.. .>........|
00000030  04 18 00 b0 ec 80 00 c0  c3 bc 0a 70 40 41 80 7a  |...........p@A.z|
00000040  4c 02 04 80 61 3c 56 80  03 16 02 0c b0 81 26 42  |L...a<V.......&B|
00000050  8f 00 41 23 4c 00 e2 f8  43 80 25 42 20 78 de 12  |..A#L...C.%B x..|
00000060  20 20 9c 01 07 90 c0 86  f0 25 40 fa 00 4f 9c 38  |  .......%@..O.8|
00000070  21 2f e1 4b 00 10 30 4d  04 88 a4 a1 50 80 50 65  |!/.K..0M....P.Pe|
00000080  2b 04 38 82 2a c0 10 2c  05 06 08 28 40 e0 80 13  |+.8.*..,...(@...|
00000090  24 00 ff 04 08 e1 db b7  13 23 b6 9d 28 f0 ff 3f  |$........#..(..?|
000000a0  40 00 d4 8b 02 0c 60 14  20 00 c8 a0 3b 02 04 0d  |@.....`. ...;...|
000000b0  3a c2 2e 01 58 20 9a ef  08 00 25 4a 00 80 c1 3a  |:...X ....%J...:|
000000c0  0d 80 40 00 6c d0 11 80  83 3e 01 00 0b 48 f3 05  |..@.l....>...H..|
000000d0  40 5e 0d 00 f4 6a 00 e8  a0 23 80 07 7d 22 12 4c  |@^...j...#..}".L|
000000e0  f3 05 20 96 05 08 00 66  d9 00 f0 41 47 00 10 ba  |.. ....f...AG...|
000000f0  23 80 2f 40 cd 17 80 be  16 20 00 68 6b 03 40 0c  |#./@..... .hk.@.|
00000100
```

Raw Files
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_LD5uCWewHncJLRlHR-X0_Zh0h7qTvFl/view

I would like to identify the compression algorithm used to compress these files so that they can be decompressed and analyzed.